# How can I use an open range (both bounds exclusive) in Swift?

Tags: swift, range

I already know that there's a built-in operator `..<` called half-open range. But how can I obtain a "both-open" range, meaning a range that doesn't contain either terminal?

To clarify using [interval notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)), if `a...b` is equivalent to [a, b] and `a..<b` is equivalent to [a, b), what is the Swift equivalent of (a, b)?

Ideally, I would prefer to do this using native Swift functionality. But if this is not possible, could I extend `Range` to achieve this?

I tried in some ways, but I still don't know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As regards extending `Range`, SwiftLee author Antoine Van Der Lee describes how to define custom operators here:  https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/custom-operators-swift/

Using the Custom Infix Operator example from the linked blog post as a template, I came up with this extension to define your 'both-open' range:

```
import Foundation

infix operator >-<: RangeFormationPrecedence
extension Int {
    static func >-< (lhs: Int, rhs: Int) -> ClosedRange<Int> {
        return ClosedRange(uncheckedBounds: (lower: lhs + 1, upper: rhs - 1))
    }
}

for i in 5>-<8 {
    print(i)
}
```

Note that although the result is a `Range` (specifically a `ClosedRange<Int>`), the operator itself is actually defined on `Int`.

Running the above example code in a Swift Playground produces the output

```
6
7
```

so you can see that by using the custom infix operator `>-<`, the resulting 'both-open' range starts from a number 1 greater than the lower bound, and goes up to a number 1 less than the upper bound.

(I tried defining the operator as `>.<` to parallel the half-open range operator `..<`, but Xcode objected.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `nextUp` on most Floating Point numbers.

```
let lowerBound: Double = 3.0
let upperBound: Double = 5.0
let openRange = lowerBound.nextUp..<upperBound
```

(Where `openRange` includes all values between `3.0` and `5.0` but does not include `3.0` or `5.0`)

`Int` doesn't have this by default, but you could extend it and do the same thing.

```
extension Int {
    var nextUp: Int {
        self + 1
    }
}
```